# Is it ethical to give/donate/sell placebo pills marketed as "miracle" pills, if people actually get better?

Tags: ethics

It's seems well known that the placebo effect exists, so if a company were to sell/donate a pill that "helped symptoms of Irritable Bowel Syndrome." Would this be okay if a large number patients/customers actually felt better after taking these pills? When would it be okay and when would it not?

I am imagining a situation where they meet FDA requirements and even just listed ingredients as "Sugar", but people bought them anyway because they simply don't pay that much attention.

Comment: It could be ok only if there is full disclosure that the pill is placebo, but that would kill the placebo effect unless indeed people aren't paying attention. But then it is their fault. Otherwise ethically it is fraud perpetrated by the company, whether it meets the legal definition or not.

Comment: Putting legality aside, i suppose.. would it be ethical if people benefited from "not knowing"?

Comment: When I consume sugar, it makes _me_ feel better... more seriously though, this question as asked is quite broad. I would narrow it down (Who says that it would be ethical? What does a specific philosopher think about it?). Also, the claim "It's seems well known that the placebo effect exists" probably needs some citation.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, there is the question of *which* system of ethics are you using? Although the terms ethics and ethical tend used generically as if they were a fixed set of principles, you actually have to specify which ethical system you're using before determining whether an act is ethical or not. Different ethical systems prescribe different courses of action for identical situations. See Cort Ammon's response for example on the difference between how the placebo example would be perceived in Western medicine and how this would be perceived in Chinese medicine.

In the placebo case you mentioned, it is possible to look at it in two ways:

- In a [consequentialist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consequentialism) or [utilitarian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utilitarianism) ethics, i.e. one were we based our judgement on the positive outcome of our actions, it is possible to argue that it is indeed ethical for this company to sell placebo pills, provided they somehow prove beyond a reasonable doubt that this placebo approach works better than real medicine.
- In [a deontological ethics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deontological_ethics), i.e. a rule or duty based ethical system, selling the placebo would most likely be wrong. In particular one could use Kant's approach to see that selling the placebo doesn't satisfy [the categorical imperative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categorical_imperative): If one company started selling placebos to cure one ailment, then all companies could start selling placebos and eventually the entire pharmaceuticals industry would be in the business of doing nothing more than packaging various flavors of sugar pills. Or one could go a step deeper and argue that deception is necessary for this schema to work, and since deception can't be universalized under the categorical imperative, any form of deception, even that which might have occasional positive effects is unethical.

I think that pragmatically speaking, in your case, ultimately the Kantian approach "wins". For placebos to work, there has to be some form of deception. Maintaining that deception indefinitely is impossible, and deception in general and in the medical profession in particular is very dangerous. The negative consequences of allowing pharma companies to sell placebos in general far outweigh the benefits of this one placebo effect (See I even managed to reconcile the Kantian view and the utilitarian view).

Comment: +1 for shouting out the contingency of ethical judgement on the parameters of evaluation.

Answer (score 0):

Its ethical considerations vary from culture to culture.

In western culture, it is unethical to prescribe a medicine whose effects are believed to be purely placebo.  For example, a psychiatrist can get in *great* trouble for prescribing sugar pills, even if they work.

In China, Traditional Chinese Medicine has a different approach.  They treat the patient holistically.  The fact that they had to use the mind to cause the effect is not as important as the fact that it helped the patient resolve their issues.  They have their own way of validating such medicines of course, typically associated with Chi rather than "proven" in a Western style peer reviewed journal.  Accordingly, we find much of what they do qualifies as "placebo effect" in strict Western science, causing many in the West to discard TCM as a useless art.

Both approaches have their value, so the acceptability of such cures is very much a cultural question.  In America, we are even seeing a blurring of the two.  Anecdotally, I know of a professor of physics who needed knee surgery.  The rehabilitation program afterwards was useful, of course, but it left a great deal unanswered.  In particular, the best they could advise for pain was drugs, because that was all that was scientifically proven.  He elected to test out acupuncture as a solution.   The result: he found his pain subsided.  He readily recognizes that his experience was not in any way a scientific trial of the value of acupuncture, but for him, it worked.  That was good enough.  It's perhaps not identical to your scenario, because he knew going into it that there was no recognized scientific basis for acupuncture providing relief, but its hopefully similar enough to help understand how nuanced the ethical considerations can be.

Answer (score -1):

Whether an action is ethical or not cannot be **read off** from nature, resulting in a unique answer. Because people **determine** what they consider ethically allowed or ethically prohibited, often in accordance with their society but sometimes also in opposition to it.

Anyhow I consider it good practice in Western countries to evaluate the effect of new drugs before releasing them. And also to make case studies about the effect of placebos.

In case no effect - neither positive nor negative - has been detected with sufficient significance, the physician can tell his patient about this state of affairs and let him decide about taking the drug or not.

I am sure that many patients will refuse to be treated by placebos without knowing it. Because the number of mature patients increases, who want to be elucidated about their illness and about the type of the medical treatment.

Answer (score -1):

I think it's unethical to officially prescribe these medications, but it would be okay to sell them OTC a provided they make it clear that there is no evidence they work beyond placebo. This is based on utilitarianism- the greatest good for the most people in the longest term.

The reason I say it is unethical to percribe these is because in medicine, doctors should get the full, knowledgable consent of their patients. A placebo won't work, or at least won't work as well, if the patient does not know that it is a placebo. Some may argue that the issue of consent can mostly be ruled out: the patient can be told they are taking a pill that has been shown in clinical trials to be effective for certain conditions, and that it has no side effects. However, this is just the superficial description of the medication. The doctor would be withholding relevant information from their patient, because they know that without it the patient would likely refuse and demand a more harmful drug.

While on the surface this does seem to be for the greater good- the patient reduces their symptoms and does not take a medication with harmful side effects- it has the important effect of reducing a patient's and society's trust of their physicians. When a person learns that their physician will bend the truth to favor their personal favorite diagnosis and medicine, a patient may for example refuse regular breast exams. It is also important to note that a patient getting a placebo already is less likely to be knowledgeable of medicine (else they would be in the habit of reading up on their prescriptions and find that it's placebo) and already biased towards distrusting doctors.

So, while it may be more ethical to perscribe placebo on a small-scale basis, it has large scale effects that make it unethical in my view when applying a utilitarian ethical view.

Comment: Welcome on Philosophy.SE! There is some good argumentation, but your answer could be improved by basing it on references to academic/historical philosophers and their positions rather than mere opinion, because that's what we're looking for in the first place.